# Architecture for multiple Whatsapp rooms by using Twilio conversations

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'd like to inquire about the current options available for creating WhatsApp group conversations for users.

Here's the scenario:

User 1 wishes to engage in a WhatsApp conversation with multiple users simultaneously, such as User 2, User 3, and User 4. I intend to facilitate this communication using proxy connections so that my internal number or profile can connect User 1 with User 2, User 1 with User 3, and so forth.

My initial plan involved using distinct phone numbers(Twilio senders) for each pair of communications through proxy connections. **I know that it should be unique pair of Twilio number + User number.**

Now, for my question:

Are there any alternative methods to achieve this, considering that WhatsApp/Meta, currently permits the connection of only two numbers with one Business API profile?

Configured & connected two different numbers for the communication. It will allow to communicate User 1 with User 2 and User 1 with User 3.